# CSS transition duration not applying on first instance of transition effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a series of sliding divs triggered on press of a button. The idea is that each div will have a thumbnail and some text tied to it. Upon clicking left/right button, the divs will move their position accordingly.

My code can be seen in the jsfiddle below. I'm encountering 3 problems:

1) The "transition: left 2s" rule isn't applying on the first transition effect, it does on the subsequent ones.

2) I'd like the repeat pressing of the corresponding buttons to apply the left property value again so that I can slide the divs repeatedly.

3) Instead of the "right" button re-positioning the "left" property back to 0, I'd like to shift it back in the opposite direction with the previous left property value.

Essentially I'm trying to recreate the slider found on this side.

http://www.euphoriumbakery.com/

Any help or input will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your help.

https://jsfiddle.net/kshatriiya/g709swLg/1/

```js
window.onload = function() {



  $("#left").on("click", function() {


    $("#view").css("left", "-262px");


  });

  $("#right").on("click", function() {


    $("#view").css("left", "0px");


  });

}
```

```css
#galwrapper {
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#view {
  position: relative;
  width: 1423px;
  transition: left 2s;
}
.col-md {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 18%;
}
.thumb img {
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="galwrapper">
  <div id="view">

    <div class="col-md">
      <div class="thumb">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="http://netdna.walyou.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/retrocake1.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Retro Cake</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md">
      <a href="#" class="thumb active">
        <img class="img-rounded" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dh8ii5sbvyc/maxresdefault.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Strawberry Cake</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md" id="mid">
      <a href="#" class="thumb">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dh8ii5sbvyc/maxresdefault.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Retro Cake</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: **Transition only works on an existing property** .. You need to **set the `left` property to a value in your CSS**, before your JavaScript takes effect and adds the `left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#view {
 position: relative;
 width: 1423px;
 left:0;
 transition: left 2s;
}
```

Initially make `left:0;` for the div with id view https://jsfiddle.net/81tqeof4/6/

and for sliding effect get the current left position and update the position.check fiddle for an  example

```
$("#left").on("click", function(){

    var leftPosition =  parseInt($("#view").position().left) - 256; 

     $("#view").css("left", -Math.abs(leftPosition));

 });
```

Comment: If you want to make it continuous take the position of element and  add that on click.I have updated the fiddle please check

Comment: **Skip the units** when you are using `0` as the value. `left:0;` should be fine

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have upvoted all the replies, however it may not show up because I don't have high enough reputation to make public upvote or something.

Answer (score 0):

> `transition` works only on an **existing property**

So initially(in your CSS) you do not have a `left` property available in your `#view`. It is only later **on a click that your JavaScript adds the `left`** and your transition starts working.

So basically you need to set the `left` property to a value in your CSS, before your JavaScript takes effect and adds the left

```
#view {
  position: relative;
  width: 1423px;
  left: 0; //initiate
  transition: left 2s;
}
```

Comment: Cheers..Accept an answer so it can help others as well.